# How to compare values in different data frames in R (by column values)?

Tags: r

Unfortunately could not find the relevant answer. Would appreciate help.

Let us assume we have two data frames in R.

First data frame shows the results of trades containing the trade numbers and values, fees values & Exchange codes.

```
> df1
  EXCH Fee1 Fee2 Fee3  Trade Numb     Trade Value
1 CHD   2   20    1        123            5639
2 BHD  10   25    2        231            3423
3 SPP   5   23    1        523           (3636)
4 HSB  11   2     3        425            ....
5 HSB  11   2     3        233
6 SPP   5   23    1        124
7 CHD   2   20    1        123  
....
```

Second data frame shows the correct fees value for particular exchange.

```
> df2
 EXCH Fee1 Fee2 Fee3
1 CHD   2   20    1
2 BHD  10   25    2
3 SPP   5   23    1
4 HSB  11   2     3
....
```

The task is to validate the fee values in the data frame 1 by comparing the trade results with the data in data frame 2. Meaning I need to find to find the exchange code in df 1 and find the fees values with the same exchange code in the df2. In the end I should get something like this:

```
 > df1
  EXCH Fee1 Fee2 Fee3  Trade Numb   Validation
1 CHD   2   20    1        123          TRUE
2 BHD  10   25    2        231          TRUE
3 SPP   5   22    5        523          FALSE
4 HSB  11   2     3        425          TRUE
5 HSB  11   2     3        233          TRUE
6 SPP   5   23    1        124          TRUE
....                                    ...
```

Data frames are of a different size as the df2 only contains the benchmark for every exchnage and df1 contains results of many trade deals.

Any ideas on how to do that in R?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are the data frames the same size matching one-to-one?

Comment: No, data frames have different size. df1 has a lot of different trade deals but for every deal there is a specific exchange code that can be matched with exchange code in df2. df2 only consists of unique exchange codes and the relevant fees values for each exchange.

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(EXCH = LETTERS)
df1 <- rbind(df1, df1, df1)
df1 <- cbind(df1, data.frame(Fee1 = sample(26 * 3), 
                             Fee2 = sample(26 * 3), 
                             Fee3 = sample(26 * 3), 
                             Trade_Num = 1:(26*3)))
df2 <- df1[1:26, 1:4]
```

**Base**

```
df1$Validated <- duplicated(rbind(df1[, 1:4], df2), fromLast = T)[1:NROW(df1)] & 
                 duplicated(rbind(df2, df1[, 1:4]))[(NROW(df2) + 1):(NROW(df1) + NROW(df2))])
```

**Explanation**

Look for `duplicated` rows when your `rbind` both `df1` and `df2` from bottom to top. This however would also select rows wrongly, which are are duplicate within df1 alone but do not have a correspondence in `df2`. Thus, make sure that those rows are also a duplicate from the top when you `rbind` `df2` and `df1`.

**dplyr**

```
df2$Validated <- TRUE
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Validated = !is.na(Validated))
```

**Explanation**

You join the 2 data sets in a way that all rows from  `df1` are in the final solution and `NA` is returned if there is no match. Then all you have to do is to replace `NA` by `FALSE`.